# Get BASE in HTML after it has been set, but not using page URL

Tags: javascript, html, radix

The base is dynamically set in php when an HTML page is built:

```
$base_line = '<base href="' . $some_path . '/" /> ';
echo $base_line;
```

Now that I am in the HTML page I need to access this information ($some_path) and after searching for a few hours I don't seem to find an answer. Please note that the loaded HTML page has a URL that is not related to the base and I don't have access to the PHP code to modify it. The loaded page could have a URL like: http://xyz.com/index.php, but all other links in the page will be based on the value set by the base so I can't get the base using the page URL.

I suppose I could grab one of the elements like an image and dissect it using DOM to find the base, but there should be an easier way to do this. Any ideas?

Using window.location doesn't work in this situation as it will return what is related to the loaded page URL and not what has been set as base within it.

Comment: Did you try `document.getElementsByTagName('base')`? In any case, `BASE` is something you should try to avoid. It has weird effects in various browsers, including trying to load JS twice from both the BASE and non-BASE location.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Update 3**

As @jorgecasar mentioned [in his answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832690/get-base-in-html-after-it-has-been-set-but-not-using-page-url/55922105#55922105), there is now a property, `baseURI` on every `Node` (which includes every `Element`).

Calling `document.baseURI` will get you the base path to the page, taking into account the `<base>` tag.

Note that it is a recent-ish property that is supported by all modern browsers, but if you are using older browsers you might either want to stick with the older answers or make sure you have a poly- or ponyfill for it (Babel's standard polyfill seems to include one, though I couldn't find specific documentation saying as much).

Also, note that `document.baseURI` will give you a fully-qualified absolute path, whereas getting the `href` attribute from `<base>` will give you the exact value you provided, so there may be a slight difference in the usage of the two.

---

**Original**

If you want to get the value of the base element, you can do something like:

```
var baseHref = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href
```

Or to be a little safer:

```
var bases = document.getElementsByTagName('base');
var baseHref = null;

if (bases.length > 0) {
    baseHref = bases[0].href;
}
```

---

Update: a more concise way would be:

```
const baseHref = (document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0] || {}).href;
```

`baseHref` may be null if it doesn't have a `<base>`.

---

Update 2: Instead of using `getElementsByTagName()`, use `querySelector()`:

```js
var base = (document.querySelector('base') || {}).href;
console.log(base);
```

```html
<base href="http://www.google.com"/>
```

Comment: I would just assign an id to the `<base>` like `<base id="myBase" href="..."/>` and then `document.getElementById('myBase').href`.

Comment: @Blaise Why would you add the extra unncessary HTML though?

Answer (score 10):

No need for jquery, jqlite, or obsolete APIs. Use the newer `querySelector` API:

```
var base = document.querySelector('base');
var baseUrl = base && base.href || '';
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Answer (score 8):

One issue I ran into is that using `element.href` doesn't return exactly what is set.  For example, if you have this:

```
<base href="/some/sub/directory/" />
```

Then `element.href` will give you:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href
# http://example.com/some/sub/directory/
```

I found that you can avoid this by using the jQuery `attr` function:

```
$("base").attr("href")
# /some/sub/directory/
```

If you want to avoid jQuery, you can also use the `getAttribute` function:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute("href")
# /some/sub/directory/
```

Answer (score 6):

Every Node has a readonly property [baseURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI) that returns the absolute base URL or null if unable to obtain an absolute URI.

To obtain the base URL of a document you can use: `document.baseURI`.

If you only want the pathname or any other part of the URL you can create a [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) object:

```
var baseLocation = new URL(document.baseURI);
var pathname = baseLocation.pathname;
```

Comment: I updated my answer to include info about `baseURI`. I've been using that myself lately.

Comment: @samanime you can include a link to the answer like [jorgecasar mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55922105/1024661)

Comment: Added a link. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using javascript `window.location.hostname` if you don't have access to PHP

If you want something like

```
http://www.example.com/blahblah/blah.html
```

Than these 3 things comes in action

```
window.location.protocol = "http"
window.location.host = "example.com"
window.location.pathname = "blahblah/blah.html"

var url = window.location.protocol + "://" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
```

You can look at this [article](http://arifhossen.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/javascript-get-base-url/) for a base url function

Comment: I'm not getting how that will tell you what the BASE is.

Comment: @Alien, that would return the base for the page not what is set for the base.

Comment: @Alien, I know this might be confusing, but I try: I want the base THAT IS SET IN THE HEAD OF THE CURRENT PAGE and not the base of the page URL. You can load a page http://xyz.com/test.php, but setting the base in that page to http://some.other.domain/ and have all the relative links in your test.php to be served by what is set in as base. I hope this clears it up :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jqLite(The angularjs default), the code looks like:

```
base = angular.element(document.querySelector('base')).attr('href')
```

See [angular document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) for more details.

Comment: But solution provided uses http://vanilla-js.com/ which is better than needing angular for such a simple task.  The solution work even when you are using angular as well in your app, like all vanilla-js solutions :)

Comment: A more concise way if using angular: `base = $document.find('base').attr('href')`